# Data sent to and received from server

Tags: networking

For example, some software send data to server in order to receive other data. I'd like to see what exactly and how is that data sent and received, so I could somehow communicate with server without that software.

Comment: So... What is the question? Are you asking for software? Software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: I understand he wants to know how to find which of his software (or what part of Windows) is sending and receiving data in the background.

Comment: perhaps this is a packet inspection question?

Comment: Wireshark is the tool you are looking for, before you have more question please look and read manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a program to dump the traffic - TCPDump under Linux (don't do Windows, but Windump s apparently the equivalent for windows)

Also look at Wireshark, or, if you are using "proper" routers, Netflow.

Comment: Wireshark is exactly what I wanted, thank you!